# JS OOP: Access descendant's constructor from parent method

Tags: javascript, class

I have next classes:

```
class Type {
    static fromObject(obj = {}) {
        return <new descendant object>
    }
}

class CustomType1 extends Type {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class CustomType2 extends Type {
    constructor(c, d) {
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
}

const t1 = CustomType1.fromObject({a:1, b:2})
const t2 = CustomType2.fromObject({c:3, d:4})
```

Expected result: t1 is instance of CustomType1 and t2 is instance of CustomType2

Question: It's possible to access child's class or prototype or constructor from parent class through static context in order to use method as factory.

Comment: You might want to try using `new.target` to get access to the constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target

Comment: For `CustomType1.fromObject` the `this` in `fromObject` refers to `CustomType1`, and for `CustomType2.fromObject` the `this` refers to `CustomType2`, isn't that enough in your case?

Comment: Mostly you're just looking for `return new this()`. The trickier part is to deconstruct the object into positional arguments…

Answer (score 1):

The `this` within the `fromObject` will like for any other function that you call (except arrow function that do  context binding) refer to object on which it is called, so in your case, it would be `CustomType1` and `CustomType2`. `CustomType1` and `CustomType2` are the *constructor* of those classes.

```
class Type {
 static fromObject(obj = {}) {
    return new this(obj.a, obj.b)
  }
}
```